# Why can't I access my bucket from an assumed role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket with no attached ACLs or policies. It was created by terraform like so:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "runners_cache" {
  bucket = var.runners_cache.bucket
}
```

I created a role and attached a policy to it; see the following console log for details

```
$ aws iam get-role --role-name bootstrap-test-bootstrapper
{
    "Role": {
{
    "Role": {
        "Path": "/bootstrap-test/",
        "RoleName": "bootstrap-test-bootstrapper",
        "RoleId": "#SNIP",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:role/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-bootstrapper",
... #SNIP


$ aws iam list-attached-role-policies --role-name bootstrap-test-bootstrapper
{
    "AttachedPolicies": [
        {
            "PolicyName": "bootstrap-test-bootstrapper",
            "PolicyArn": "arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:policy/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-bootstrapper"
        },
... #SNIP


$ aws iam get-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:policy/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-runner
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "bootstrap-test-runner",
        "PolicyId": "#SNIP",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:policy/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-runner",
        "Path": "/bootstrap-test/",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v7",
... #SNIP


$ aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:policy/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-runner --version-id v7
{
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "Document": {
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                        "s3:CompleteMultipartUpload",
                        "s3:ListBucket",
                        "s3:PutObject",
                        "s3:GetObject",
                        "s3:DeleteObject",
                        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                    ],
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::#SNIP-runners-cache/*",
                        "arn:aws:s3:::#SNIP-cloud-infrastructure-terraform-states/*"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:*"
                    ],
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "VersionId": "v7",
        "IsDefaultVersion": true,
        "CreateDate": "2022-08-18T14:16:33+00:00"
    }
}
```

tl;dr this role has an attached policy that allows full access to s3 within the account.

I can successfully assume this role:

```
$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::#SNIP:role/bootstrap-test/bootstrap-test-bootstrapper --role-session-name test123
{ ... #REDACTED }
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ASIA2 #REDACTED
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=8 #REDACTED
$ export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=IQoJb #REDACTED
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "#SNIP",
    "Account": "#SNIP",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::#SNIP:assumed-role/bootstrap-test-bootstrapper/test123"
}
```

However, once I do this, I no longer have access to S3:

```
$ aws s3 ls #SNIP-runners-cache

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
$ aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

What am I missing? Is there some default behavior that prevents access to S3? How should I go about debugging these 403 errors?

Comment: How did you get your initial session from where you assume another role? Are there permission boundaries, sessions policies or SCPs in play?

Comment: @luk2302 My user has admin rights in this account.

Comment: Your policy has 2 allow statements and the 2nd allows `s3:*` on `arn:aws:s3:::*` which makes the 1st statement irrelevant. Is that just for testing? Also note that in your 1st statement you have some object-level actions (e.g. PutObject) and some bucket-level actions (e.g. ListBucket) but the listed resources are both object-level ARNs. The bucket-level actions need a bucket ARN, not an object ARN.

Comment: @jarmod Of course, the first statement is irrelevant. It was supposed to be sufficient for the actions that the role was supposed to perform, but when it didn't work, I created the 2nd statement to exclude any IAM misconfiguration issues.

Comment: @luk2302 you were right after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to get over-obsessed with the details of the policy and forget about the role itself. In this case the permissions boundary went unnoticed in the CLI, but it is quite easy to see in the web console:

[image: IAM console]

Indeed, @luk2302 was right, the limiting factor was a permissions boundary. After removing it from the role, access to S3 was restored.